# Não consigo converter para inteiro

Tags: python

Faça uma função que leia um arquivo texto contendo uma lista de endereços IP e gere dois outros arquivos, um contendo os endereços IP válidos e outro contendo
os endereços inválidos. O formato de um endereço IP é `num1.num.num.num`, onde `num1` vai de 1 a 255 e `num` vai de 0 a 255.

```
def ips(arq1):
    ipsv=open('ipsv.txt','w')
    ipsi=open('ipsi.txt','w')
    c=0
    junta=""
    for ip in arq1:
        listaip = []
        for i in range(len(ip)):
            if ip[i]!=".":
               junta=junta+ip[i]
               junta=(junta)
               if len(junta)==3:
                   listaip.append(int(junta.strip()))
                   junta=""
            else:
                continue

        print(listaip)
        for x in listaip:
            if listaip[0]>=1 and listaip[0]<=255 and x>=0 and x<=255:
                ipsv.write(str(x))
            else:
                ipsi.write(str(x))
    ipsi.close()
    ipsv.close()

arq1=open('ips.txt','r')
ips(arq1)
```

Comment: E qual é o erro? Qual linha?

Comment: File "C:/Users/lucas/PycharmProjects/uff/arquivo/5.py", line 21, in ips
    listaip.append(int(junta.strip()))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0\n1'

Comment: A mensagem de erro foi bem clara: há um caractere `\n` no meio da sua string que não pode ser convertida para inteiro.

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se entendi a pergunta, mas se seu objetivo é somente validar ip, use as bibliotecas apropriadas para isso, veja o codigo abaixo. Bonus: Informações sobre o ip digitado corretamente.
 ([tl;dr](https://repl.it/IuCS/1))

```
from IPy import IP
import ipaddress

ip = input('Entre com o ip: ')
try: 
    ipaddress.ip_address(ip)
except ValueError:
    print ('Formato invalido do ip')
else:
    # Obter informações sobre o ip
    myip =  IP(ip)
    print ('Tipo de ip: ', myip.iptype(), '\nMáscara: ',
            myip.netmask(), '\nReverse name: ', myip.reverseName())

Entre com o ip:  192.168.5.3
Tipo de ip:  PRIVATE 
Máscara:  255.255.255.255 
Reverse name:  3.5.168.192.in-addr.arpa

# Entrando com o ip errado:
Entre com o ip:  192.299.5.3
Formato invalido do ip
```

[Execute esse codigo no repl.it.](https://repl.it/IuCS/1)

Answer (score 0):

Para converter para inteiro basta fazer um cast: int(variavel).

Além disso você pode simplificar o processo criando um Array do IP usando split(). Veja o exemplo de código (Adapte ao seu código):

```
ip = '200.201.202.256'

nums = ip.split('.')

if len(nums) == 4:
    for n in nums:
        if 0 <= int(n) <= 255:
            print(n)
        else:
            print('IP Inválido!')
            break
else:
    print('IP Inválido!')
```